# sum of last month and total

Tags: sql, zend-framework

Im trying to get sum of points for a user in the last month and the total, is it possible to get it in one query? Im using zend but i can probably get it working with provided sql.

heres my total for last month

```
$select = $this->_db
            ->select()
            ->from(array('p' => $this->_name), array(
                'user_login',
                'sum' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(p.value)'),
                )
            )
            ->joinLeft(array('u' => 'user'), 'p.user_login = u.login')
            ->group('p.user_login')
            ->where('DATE(when) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY')
            ->order('sum DESC')
            ;
    return $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to show the total for the last 30 days and the total of all times for each user; sadly I can't test the Zend syntax and I'm not very used to it, but here is one version of the required SQL for MySQL;

```
SELECT p.user_login, 
  SUM(IF(DATE(`when`) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY,p.value,0)) sum,
  SUM(p.value) total_sum
FROM user_value p
JOIN user u
  ON u.login = p.user_login
GROUP BY p.user_login
ORDER BY sum DESC;
```

[SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c85b2/1).

Comment: SUM(IF(DATE(`when`) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY,p.value,0)) sum,

exatly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I believe your initial query is equivalent to this SQL:

```
SELECT p.user_login, SUM(p.value) as sum_last_month
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_login = u.login
WHERE DATE(when) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY p.user_login
ORDER BY sum_last_month DESC
```

I'm not sure how to do a nested SELECT like this with Zend, but in SQL I believe something like this would work:

```
SELECT p.user_login, SUM(p.value) as sum_last_month,
    (SELECT SUM(p2.value) FROM person p2 WHERE p2.id = p.id) as total
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_login = u.login
WHERE DATE(when) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY p.user_login
ORDER BY sum_last_month DESC, total DESC
```